# In MAUI, how do I pass data from a login page page to a tabbed page with shell navigation?

Tags: shell, navigation, maui

I am fairly new to MAUI and I am trying to pass data collected in the login page to a tabbed page. I am trying to pass the data using the shell navigation method but it does not appear to be available on any of my tab pages.

The navigation code:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//PortalTabs", true, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    //Data that must be passed to App page
    {"User", user}
});
```

Using Maui Community toolkit, on the first tab(AppViewModel):

```
//Data brought forward from previous page
[QueryProperty(nameof(User), "User")]

public partial class AppViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Observable Properties
    [ObservableProperty]
    UserModel user;
    
    public AppViewModel() 
    {
    }
}
```

The TabBar in AppShell.xaml:

```
<!--Portal Tabs-->
 <TabBar Route="PortalTabs">
     <Tab Title="Apps">
         <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AppPage}"/>
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Profile">
         <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProfilePage}"/>
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Settings">
         <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}"/>
     </Tab>
 </TabBar>
```

I am trying to use the data on the AppPage via:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding User.Username}"
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please remove the _shell_ tag, since the question does not match any of the [criteria for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell).

Comment: What I find very interesting, is that every question about sharing data between Views, is pretty much answered with "make your data static". And this question, that concerns one of the few things that are acceptable for similar approaches, is answered with actually passing the data.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. The routing must be to the page that requires the data, rather than routing to the TabBar. In response to Isidoros's answer: my pages did inherit from ObservableObject through ViewModelBase, and my binding context was set on the code behind of the page already.

The working navigation:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//AppPage", true, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    //Data that must be passed to App page
    {"User", user}
});
```

The route added to AppShell.xaml:

```
<!--Portal Tabs-->
<TabBar Route="PortalTabs">
    <Tab Title="Apps" Route="AppPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AppPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Profile">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProfilePage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Settings">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Answer (score -1):

The command **Shell.Current.GoToAsync** passes the parameters to the page not to the underlying viewmodel. Move your code to the page code behind.

```
//Data brought forward from previous page
[QueryProperty(nameof(User), "User")]

public partial class AppPage : ContentPage
{
    User user;
    public User User
    {
        set
        {
            user = value;
            BindingContext = new AppViewModel(user);
        }
    }

    public AppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //no binding here. Set the binding when you receive
        //the data from the property.
    }
    ....
}
```

Your view model should look like the below (note the parameter userparam and the ObservableObject inherited class is required for MVVM to work):

```
public partial class AppViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //Observable Properties
    [ObservableProperty]
    User user;
    
    public AppViewModel(User userparam) 
    {
        user = userparam;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the `BindingContext` in the constructor of the View. QueryParameters are only passed into the View after construction, which means that the bindings will get updated if you add a call to `OnPropertyChanged()` in the setter of `User`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes. However, since there is a ViewModel that holds the `User` object already, there is no need to duplicate the `User` backing field in the View. You could relay the parameter to the ViewModel in the setter.

Comment: The constructor is called before the parameters are passed to the viewmodel.

Comment: That's what I said, too. That's why you can set the `BindingContext` in the constructor, like in the official documentation. You can then use the property setter to pass the value to the ViewModel and stay MVVM compliant.

Comment: I've checked to my project, and the constructor is called first, and the property with the parameter is called 2nd. I dont know why.

Comment: And that's the correct behavior. Query parameters are **always** passed in to the View **after** construction of the page. That means that you can safely create the ViewModel in the constructor and set it as the `BindingContext` of the page. Then, when the `QueryParameter` gets assigned to the property, you can pass the value to the ViewModel from within the setter. That way, the View can still bind directly to the ViewModel's properties.